# C - Recursive, cumulative sum of an array

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I've been tasked with making a recursive function that takes an array of numbers, and turns it into an array of the cumulative sum of all the numbers up to this point, thus:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 becomes 1, 3, 6, 10, 15

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cumul(int tab[], int length, int ind) {

    if (ind > 0) {
        tab[ind] += tab[ind-1];
    }
    if (ind < length) {
        cumul(tab, length, ind+1);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int ind;
    int tab[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int length = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);

    for (ind = 0; ind < length; ind++) {
        printf("%d ", tab[ind]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    cumul(tab, length, 0);

    for (ind = 0; ind < length; ind++) {
    printf("%d ", tab[ind]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It works well in most cases but I've hit a snag for oddly specific arrays:

For example, it doesn't work for tab[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, here's the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 3 6 10 15 21 27 7 4196016 0 -1076574208 32528 -1609083416 32767 -1609083416 32767 0 1 4195802 0 0 0 -1815242402 30550560 4195424 0 -1609083424
```

I have no idea why it goes bonkers. It works fine for just about any tab[5] and tab[7] arrays I tried, but fails for every tab[6] array I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when `ind` reaches `length-1`. For example, if `length` is 6, and `ind` is 5, then the recursive call is

```
cumul(tab, 6, 6);  // length=6 ind+1=6
```

At the next level of recursion, after the `if ( ind > 0 )`, the code will do this

```
tab[6] += tab[5];  // ind=6 ind-1=5
```

That results in undefined behavior because you're writing beyond the end of the array.

You could check the upper bound in the first `if` statement, e.g.

```
if ( ind > 0 && ind < length )
```

But it's better to just avoid the recursive call by changing the second `if` statement to

```
if ( ind < length - 1 )
```

Either change avoids the situation where you access `tab[length]`.